# How to transform CSV to a nested JSON structure in DataWeave?

Tags: dataweave

I'm working on a project where I need to convert CSV data into a specific JSON format. The CSV contains information about people and their associated products, and I want to aggregate this data into a nested JSON structure where each person is an object with their details and an array of their products

the input CSV is:

```
Dan,FirstName,LastName,DateofBirth,ProductName,ProductValue
q,denis,Kriz,01/01/1980,sales cloud,1000
q,denis,kriz,01/01/1980,service cloud,2000
x,lucas,kriz,01/01/2010,marketing cloud,3000
```

Desired JSON output:

```
{
  "Dan": "q",
  "FirstName": "denis",
  "LastName": "kriz",
  "DateOfBirth": "01/01/1980",
  "Products": [
    {
      "productName": "sales cloud", 
      "productValue": 1000
    },
    {
      "productName": "service cloud",
      "productValue": 2000
    }
  ],
  "Dan": "x",
  "FirstName": "lucas",
  "LastName": "kriz",
  "DateOfBirth": "01/01/2010",
  "Products": [
    {
      "productName": "marketing cloud",
      "productValue": 3000
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's the script I tried using DataWeave:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var data = payload
var header = data[0]
var rows = data[1 to -1]

var includedFields = ["ProductName", "ProductValue"]

var groupedData = rows groupBy ($.Dan) mapObject ((value, key, index) -> {
    Dan: key,
    FirstName: value[0].FirstName,
    LastName: value[0].LastName,
    DateOfBirth: value[0].DateofBirth,
    Products: value map ((item, index) -> {
        productName: (item.ProductName as String),
        productValue: (item.ProductValue as Number)
    })
})

---
groupedData
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1:
"All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.
This includes "asking" the question to an AI generator then copy-pasting its output as well as using an AI generator to "reword" your answers." Please remove all chatGPT content and references.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help clarify your question. Include an example input, expected output and actual outputs.

Comment: the desired JSON is not correct as it duplicates the keys. it should be as below
    {
        "Dan": "x",
        "FirstName": "lucas",
        "LastName": "kriz",
        "DateOfBirth": "01/01/2010",
        "Products": [
            {
                "productName": "marketing cloud",
                "productValue": 3000
            }
        ]
    }
]

please confirm

Comment: JSON doesn't forbid duplicate keys but it is more difficult to work with them. Please answer @AnuragSharma if this is really the desired output.

Comment: @aled Thankyou for schooling me in the ways of GPT and StackOverflow. I appreciate the issues that this causes for a site like SO and will not do this again. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the below JSON as desired output

```
[
  {
    "Dan": "q",
    "FirstName": "denis",
    "LastName": "kriz",
    "DateOfBirth": "01/01/1980",
    "Products": [
      {
        "productName": "sales cloud",
        "productValue": 1000
      },
      {
        "productName": "service cloud",
        "productValue": 2000
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Dan": "x",
    "FirstName": "lucas",
    "LastName": "kriz",
    "DateOfBirth": "01/01/2010",
    "Products": [
      {
        "productName": "marketing cloud",
        "productValue": 3000
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

you can use this script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Strings
var groupedData = payload groupBy (item) -> 
    item.Dan ++ '|' ++ item.FirstName  ++ '|' ++ item.LastName ++ '|' ++ item.DateofBirth
---
valuesOf(groupedData) map ((group, index) -> {
    Dan: group[0].Dan,
    FirstName: group[0].FirstName,
    LastName: group[0].LastName,
    DateOfBirth: group[0].DateofBirth,
    Products: group map (product) -> {
        productName: product.ProductName,
        productValue: (product.ProductValue as Number)
    }
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Anurag. This does the needful. And in my case, my keys are definitely duplicated unfortunately. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend @AnuragSharma solution because the output is clearer. However if you really need duplicated keys you can use this script:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload 
    groupBy ($.Dan) 
    mapObject ((value, key) -> {
        Dan: key,
        FirstName: value[0].FirstName,
        LastName: value[0].LastName,
        DateOfBirth: value[0].DateofBirth,
        Products: value map ((item, index) -> {
            productName: (item.ProductName as String),
            productValue: (item.ProductValue as Number)
        })
    })
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Dan": "q",
  "FirstName": "denis",
  "LastName": "Kriz",
  "DateOfBirth": "01/01/1980",
  "Products": [
    {
      "productName": "sales cloud",
      "productValue": 1000
    },
    {
      "productName": "service cloud",
      "productValue": 2000
    }
  ],
  "Dan": "x",
  "FirstName": "lucas",
  "LastName": "kriz",
  "DateOfBirth": "01/01/2010",
  "Products": [
    {
      "productName": "marketing cloud",
      "productValue": 3000
    }
  ]
}
```